# Why does this function always crash when free memory?

Tags: c, winapi, memory-management

```
int gb2Utf8(const char* source, int sourceLen, void *target, int targetLen)
{
    int result = 0;
    int bufLen = strlen(source) * 2;
    wchar_t *buffer = (wchar_t *)malloc(bufLen);
    if (!buffer)
    {
        result = 1;
        goto RETURN;
    }

    //GB18030 code page: 54936
    int m2wResult = MultiByteToWideChar(54936, MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, source, -1, buffer, bufLen);
    if (!m2wResult)
    {
        result = 2;
        goto RETURN;
    }

    int w2mResult = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, WC_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, buffer, -1, (char *)target, targetLen, NULL, NULL);
    if (!w2mResult)
    {
        result = 3;
        goto RETURN;
    }

    RETURN:
    free(buffer);
    return result;
}
```

When program runs to `free(buffer)`, it will crash, but I don't know why.
If modify `bufLen` to a constant value, or remove `MultiByteToWideChar` function, it won't crash, I also don't know why.
This is the call stack when crash:

> msvcr100d.dll!_free_dbg_nolock(void * pUserData, int nBlockUse)  Line 1376 + 0x3b bytes   C++
>   msvcr100d.dll!_free_dbg(void * pUserData, int nBlockUse)  Line 1265 + 0xd bytes   C++
>   msvcr100d.dll!free(void * pUserData)  Line 49 + 0xb bytes C++
>   New.exe!gb2Utf8(const char * source, int sourceLen, void * target, int targetLen)  Line 156 + 0xc bytes   C++
>   New.exe!wWinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance, wchar_t * lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)  Line 29 + 0x11 bytes   C++
>   New.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 547 + 0x2c bytes    C
>   New.exe!wWinMainCRTStartup()  Line 371    C
>   kernel32.dll!7509339a()   
>   [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for kernel32.dll]    
>   ntdll.dll!77979ef2()  
>   ntdll.dll!77979ec5()

Comment: Tank all of you for help, there are two errors in this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last parameter for `MultiByteToWideChar()` is the number of **characters** in the widechar buffer and not the number of bytes. You pass the number of bytes, the function probably writes over the actual buffer and `free()` checks for that when compiled in debug mode.

And as Jeeva mentioned, the proper way to call this function is by calling it once with NULL output buffer, allocate the buffer with the requested size and then call it again.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps for the buffer, you need to allocate memory for the NULL terminator too:

```
int bufLen = strlen(source) * 2 + 2;
```

Comment: better yet, use `sizeof (WCHAR)`.

Answer (score 2):

You need not assume the buffer size your self, when you pass 0 as the last parameter to the function `MultiByteToWideChar` it returns the buffer size including the terminal null character. Then you can create buffer with the returned size and use it.

try this

```
int wchars_num =  MultiByteToWideChar( CP_UTF8 , 0 , source , -1, NULL , 0 );
wchar_t* buffer = (wchar_t *)malloc(wchars_num);

MultiByteToWideChar( CP_UTF8 , 0 , source  , -1, buffer , wchars_num );
// do whatever with buffer 
free(buffer) ;
```

Comment: should i change new and delete with malloc and free?

Comment: The parameter to `malloc` is the number of bytes, not elements (it doesn't even know what the element type is).

Answer (score 1):

First, let's look at :

```
if (!buffer)
{
    result = 1;
    goto RETURN;
}
```

if `malloc` function failed, it returned NULL, and then `buffer` was assigned the value NULL, then the program turned to label `RETURN` due to `goto RETURN` , then `free` function was called and `free(buffer)` means to `free(NULL)`, which is an illegal behavior.

Second, by declaring `int bufLen = strlen(source) * 2;`, you've assumed that `bufLen` will always be positive, however, it will be 0 if strlen(source)==0. malloc(0) is a undefined behavior in ANSI-C, so different platform might return different result.

Moreover, you'd better look up the usage of function `MultiByteToWideChar` carefully. Here is the link in MSDN: [MultiByteToWideChar function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, but free a NULL pointer is a legal behavior. 'The free() function deallocates the memory allocation pointed to by ptr. If ptr is a NULL pointer, no operation is performed.' - from man page

Comment: Sorry for my mistakes. After had the C99 documents checked, I realized that free(NULL) is legal. However, long time ago my teacher taught me this and I just believe him without checking it out. Sorry again.

Comment: Here is the description in C99 documents:The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation. If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by the calloc, malloc, or realloc function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc,
the behavior is undefined.